# Firedac vs DOA oracle delphi. Параметры хранимой процедуры в виде index by table

Tags: delphi, oracle, firedac

Использую для записи в БД **чужую** хранимую процедуру

```
'begin' + #13#10 +
'  pkg_x.insert(md1 => :md1,' + #13#10 +
'               md2 => :md2,' + #13#10 +
'               cnt => :cnt);' + #13#10 +
'end;';
```

где  cnt - размер массивов , 
md1, md2 - массивы чисел. Их тип определен в Oracle как is table of number index by binary_index.

Раньше использовал компоненты DOA и передавал массивы так:

```
md1:= VarArrayCreate([0, 99], varVariant);
md2 := VarArrayCreate([0, 99], varVariant);
--------
DeclareVariable('md1', otInteger);
DimPLSQLTable('md1', 100, 0);
DeclareVariable('md2 ', otInteger);
DimPLSQLTable('md2 ', 100, 0);
DeclareVariable('cnt', otInteger);
SetVariable('cnt', 100);
SetVariable('md1', md1);
SetVariable('md2', md2);
Execute;
```

выполнялось как положено.

Сейчас вместо DOA TOracleQuery нужно использовать FireDac TFDQuery так как кроссплатформенность наше все. Решил использовать технологию array DML.

```
SetLength(md1, 100);
SetLength(md2, 100)
-------------------;
FDQuery.ParamByName('md1').DataType:= ftInteger;
FDQuery.ParamByName('md2').DataType:= ftInteger;

FDQuery.ParamByName('cnt').AsInteger:= 100;
FDQuery.Params.ArraySize:= 100;
for I := 0 to 99 do
begin
  FDQuery.ParamByName('md1').Values[I]:= md1[i];
  FDQuery.ParamByName('md2').Values[I]:= md2[i];
end;
FDQuery.Execute(FDQuery.Params.ArraySize);
```

так как в справке написано, что varray не поддерживается, то как быть? Хранимую процедуру менять только в **очень крайнем случае**. При таком выполнении запроса происходит ошибка БД: кол-во или типы параметров ошибочны